# Django: A more DRY way to prevent edit/delete of objects?

Tags: python, django, django-views, tastypie

After reading the permission Django documentation, I'm still confused.
I'd like to prevent access for user to edit or delete objects they didn't own.
I dit it this way and it works:

In views.py:

```
def deleteReward(request, reward_id):
    reward = get_object_or_404(Reward, pk=reward_id)
    if reward.owner.user != request.user: # if the user linked to the reward is not the current one
        raise Exception("This reward is not yours, you can't delete it !")
    #...
```

But I think this isn't clean and DRY for two reasons:

1. In each editStuff and deleteStuff views, I'll have to write the same portion of code.
2. I'm currently writing an API with Tastypie, and if the permission logic is in a view, I won't be able to re-use it. The best way to deals with seems to be to map the API permission with the Django permissions (but the code I wrote in my view has nothing to do with permissions).

Could you help me to find the right way to do?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm more familiar with Rails than Django so I can't give a domain-specific answer, but you should move that logic into your model.  `Reward` would have a class method `delete_if_owned` or what have you.

Comment: I agree with that, but that doesn't prevent me from writing this method in all the models that I want to delete. What about the API?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my working example.

1) QuerySet

```
class PermissionQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def editable_by(self, user):
        return self.filter(user=user)

    def viewable_by(self, user):
        return self.filter(user=user)
```

2) Managers

```
class PermissionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return PermissionQuerySet(self.model)

    def editable_by(self, user, *args):
        return self.get_query_set().editable_by(user, *args)

    def viewable_by(self, user, *args):
        return self.get_query_set().viewable_by(user, *args)
```

3) Models

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = PermissionManager()
```

This approach works perfectly with class based views. I see you using TastyPie. I never used it before but it seems it's uses class based views too.

This is working sample:

```
class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(MyUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_query_set(self):
        queryset = super(MyUpdateView, self).get_query_set()
        queryset = queryset.editable_by(self.request.user)
        if not queryset.exists():
            raise Exception("This reward is not yours, you can't delete it !")
        return queryset
```

I think you can imagine how to use this approach in CreateView, DeleteView. And i think it is easy to implement this in TastyPie.

Answer (score 1):

Pass an additional parameter to `get_object_or_404`:

```
reward = get_object_or_404(Reward, pk=reward_id, owner=request.user)
```

Comment: Smart and simple, thx. But even it's easier to write, that still does not solve the "problem" with API. Maybe there is no special solution to my problem.

Comment: By API problem do you mean reuse?

Comment: Yes. I actually created custom Authorizations for each Ressources I have in Tastypie. This is not dry, but it may be the only way to do it.