# Check if user has access to object

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to check if a user.profile has acess to a see all of a benefit object, based on the member package. (If the user does not have access, he should be able to see some fields of the object (name and package)

If a user has memberpackage `Package1` and is viewing a benefit which is in `Package1`, he should be able to see the `body` field. If the user has memberpackage `Package2` he should not be able to see the `body` field.

Is this possible? Maybe this could be done with a templatetag? `{% if user_has_access_to_benfit %}` and it would return true or false.

Something like this:

```
{{ object.name }}

{% if user_has_access_to_benfit %}
    {{ object.body }}
{% else %}
    <p>Sorry! You don't have access to this object.</p>
{% endif %}
```

-

Here is what I have tried, based on answers:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    memberpackage = models.ForeignKey(Package, blank=True, null=True)



class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)    

class Benefit(models.Model):
    PUBLISHED = 'P'
    DRAFT = 'U'
    PULLED = 'X'
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="Only visible to those members in the same memberpackage")    
    package = models.ManyToManyField(Package, blank=True, null=True, related_name="in_package")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=DRAFT)    



    def is_viewable_by(self, user):
        return self.package.filter(id=user.profile.memberpackage_id).exists()
```

## Edit:

If I do this (with capital B in Benefit)

```
#View for listing one benefit
class BenefitDetailView(DetailView):

    template_name_field = 'template_name'

    model = Benefit        

    queryset = Benefit.objects.exclude(status="X")


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            context['user_has_access_to_benfit'] = Benefit.is_viewable_by(request.user)
```

I get this error:

`unbound method is_viewable_by() must be called with Benefit instance as first argument (got User instance instead)`

## Edit 2:

Trying another way

```
#View for listing one benefit
class BenefitDetailView(DetailView):

    template_name_field = 'template_name'

    model = Benefit

    queryset = Benefit.objects.exclude(status="X")


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user_has_access_to_benfit = Benefit.objects.filter(package = request.user.profile.memberpackage).exists() #Hoping this function returns true or false
        #The user is not logged in, user_has_access_to_benfit should be set to False
        else:
            user_has_access_to_benfit = False

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(BenefitDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a extra context
        context['user_has_access_to_benfit'] = user_has_access_to_benfit
        return context
```

But I get the error: `The view app.views.BenefitDetailView didn't return an HttpResponse object.`

Not sure if there is another way of getting `request.user.is_authenticated()` in DetailView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Benefit` class:

```
Benefit(models.Model):
  ...
  def is_viewable_by(self, user):
      return self.package.filter(id=user.profile.memberpackage_id).exists()
```

In your `BenefitDetailView` class:

```
BenefitDetailView(DetailView):
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(BenefitDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.object and self.request.user.is_authenticated():
      context.update({ 'has_benefit_access': self.object.is_viewable_by(self.request.user)})
    return context
```

As `is_viewable_by` is an instance method, and not a class method, you need to call it on an instance of `Benefit`. `self.object` is the instance you want to use. The `request` object is available in every subclass of `View` as `self.request`.

If not every authenticated user has an associated profile, keep in mind that `is_viewable_by` will throw an `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception that needs to  be caught.

In this case there is absolutely no need to override the `get` method, but if you do, it needs to return a `HttpResponse` object. The easiest way to ensure this is to return the value of the superclass' `get` method:

```
class BenefitDetailView(DetailView):
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # ***do stuff***
    return super(BenefitDetailView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you. I'll award you the bounty when I'm allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `benefit` is the benefit object you want to test, in your view:

```
user_has_access_to_benfit = request.user.profile.memberpackage in benefit.package.all()
```

Then put `user_has_access_to_benfit` in your context.

Comment: I get this error if I try your code: `'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Benefit(models.Model):
    ...
    def is_viewable_by(self, user):
        return self.package.filter(id=user.profile.memberpackage_id).exists()
```

then in view:

```
context['user_has_access_to_benfit'] = benefit.is_viewable_by(request.user)
```

after your question's update you need to checkout my another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22183068/1420159

Comment: If I do `benefit.is_viewable_by(request.user)` I get this error: `global name 'benefit' is not defined`. If I add `benefit = Benefit.objects.all()` first I get this error: `QuerySet' object has no attribute 'is_viewable_by'`

Comment: @Garreth00 `benefit` is `Benefit` instance. Like `benefit` = Benefit.objects.get(id=id)

Comment: It seems to me, that in your other answer I will exclude the object for those who does not have premission. Or I'm I wrong?

Comment: Okey, thats not what Im trying to do. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

@Audrey: you forgot the `self` parameter in your method definition:

```
def is_viewable_by(self, user):
    ...              ^
```